# send python variable to powershell and vice-versa

Tags: python, powershell, variables

i would like to know how to send a variable from python to powershell and vice-versa:

I'm writing a code to get the infos of a install.wim file in the windows installation disk.

I want a result like this:

(python input) `path = input("WIM file path: ")`;
(powershell background command) `$wim_infos = Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $python_input_path`;
(powershell command) `py .\main.py $wim_infos`;
(python command) `print('Your WIM file infos:')`;
(python output) `print(sys.argv[1])`;

i tried to code this but i dont know how to send the python input path variable to powershell...

sorry if I wasn't clear, I made some mistakes, or I asked for something obvious, but I'm not very good at these things...

Comment: I may be wrong here but for this to work, Powershell would need to access the portion of memory where Python saved your variable. A workaround for this could be make Python export `path` to disk and then make Powershell read that file.

Comment: ok. thank you. I wil try to do this by writing a text file with path and reading it with powershell.